# Searching in multiple XML files for a match

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, xpath

This is my `general.xml` file: [general.xml](http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=22.298569900000000000&lng=70.794301799999970000&radius=7000)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<results xmlns="http://gisgraphy.com">
    <numFound>1</numFound>
    <QTime>67</QTime>
    <result>
        <distance>1139.81967842778</distance>
        <name>Rājkot</name>
        <adm1Code>09</adm1Code>
        <adm1Name>State of Gujarāt</adm1Name>
        <asciiName>Rajkot</asciiName>
        <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
        <featureClass>P</featureClass>
        <featureCode>PPL</featureCode>
        <featureId>1258847</featureId>
        <gtopo30>139</gtopo30>
        <population>1177362</population>
        <timezone>Asia/Kolkata</timezone>
        <lat>22.299999237060547</lat>
        <lng>70.78333282470703</lng>
        <placeType>City</placeType>
        <oneWay>false</oneWay>
        <length>0.0</length>
        <google_map_url>http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;amp;iwloc=addr&amp;amp;om=1&amp;amp;z=12&amp;amp;q=R%C4%81jkot&amp;amp;ll=22.329999237060548,70.78333282470703</google_map_url>
        <yahoo_map_url>http://maps.yahoo.com/broadband?mag=6&amp;amp;mvt=m&amp;amp;lon=70.78333282470703&amp;amp;lat=22.299999237060547</yahoo_map_url>
        <country_flag_url>/images/flags/IN.png</country_flag_url>
    </result>
</results>
```

This is my `region.xml` file:

```
<childrens>
    <child_4893 entity_id="4893" value="Gujarat" parent_id="4823">
        <child_4894 entity_id="4894" value="Ahmedabad" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4895 entity_id="4895" value="Anand" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4896 entity_id="4896" value="Bharuch (Broach)" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4897 entity_id="4897" value="Bhavnagar" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4898 entity_id="4898" value="Bhuj" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4899 entity_id="4899" value="Gandhidham" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4900 entity_id="4900" value="Gandhinagar" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4901 entity_id="4901" value="Godhra" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4902 entity_id="4902" value="Jamnagar" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4903 entity_id="4903" value="Junagadh" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4904 entity_id="4904" value="Morvi" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4905 entity_id="4905" value="Nadiad" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4906 entity_id="4906" value="Navsari" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4907 entity_id="4907" value="Patan" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4908 entity_id="4908" value="Porbandar" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4909 entity_id="4909" value="Rajkot" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4910 entity_id="4910" value="Surat" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4911 entity_id="4911" value="Surendranagar" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4912 entity_id="4912" value="Vadodara (Baroda)" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4913 entity_id="4913" value="Vejalpur" parent_id="4893"/>
        <child_4914 entity_id="4914" value="Veraval" parent_id="4893"/>
    </child_4893>
</childrens>
```

This is my `product.xml` file:

```
<products>
    <product_id value="1">
        <tab_id>
            <tab_name value="test1" />
            <dist_region value="4909"/>
            <dist_region value="4909"/>
            <dist_region value="4909"/>
        </tab_id>
    </product_id>
</products>
```

### Explanation

1. In `general.xml` file there is one node element called `<name>`, it's a `store-city` name.
2. Check if this city name exist in `region.xml` file, copy corresponding `entity_id`.
3. Check if this `entity_id` present in `product.xml` file, return the corresponding `product_id` if exists.

### e.g:

- take `<name>Rajkot</name>` from `general.xml`
- `Rajkot` exists in `region.xml` and corresponding `entity_id` is `4909`
- `entity_id` value `4909` exists in `product.xml` and corresponding `product_id` attribute value is `1`
- return `product_id` value `1`

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, please rephrase your question. What do you mean with "is exit"?

Comment: What are you looking for? Help with Javascript Xpath? You should do the actual scripting logic yourself...

Comment: How does your Javascript get the XML Docs (contents)? Via Ajax? Inline? No idea? [Examples with XML Xpath on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Evaluating_against_an_XML_document_within_an_Extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP simplexml do this: --> see live-demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ax2LtQ

```
// $g holds general.xml, $r region.xml, $p product.xml 

$general = simplexml_load_string($g);
$region = simplexml_load_string($r);
$product = simplexml_load_string($p);

$name = (string)$general->result->name;
$name = 'Rajkot' // <--- see explanation below!

if (strlen(trim($name))==0) exit('name not found');

list($entity) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$name']/@entity_id");
$entity=(string)$entity;

if (strlen(trim($entity))==0) exit('entity_id not found');

list($prid) = $product->xpath("//dist_region[@value='$entity']/ancestor::product_id/@value");
$prid=(string)$prid;

echo "name: $name, entity_id: $entity, product_id: $prid";
```

**Explanation**: in `general.xml`, `<name>` = `Rājkot`, in `region.xml` it's `Rajkot`, without the special `a`-character. To get the code working, I had to set `$name`to `Rajkot`.
You need to find a solution for this.